# scala turn List of Strings to a key/value map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a single ordered array of strings imported from an external system in the form of:

```
val l = List("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", etc...)
```

what's the scala way to turn this into a map where I can get iterate over the keys and get the associated vals?

thx

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is similar to Daniel's but I would use `collect` instead of `map`:

```
l.grouped(2).collect { case List(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
```

If you have a list with an unmatched key this won't throw an exception:

```
scala>   val l = List("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", "key3")
l: List[String] = List(key1, val1, key2, val2, key3)

scala> l.grouped(2).collect { case List(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
res22: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2)

scala> l.grouped(2).map { case List(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
scala.MatchError: List(key3) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

Some context, `grouped` returns a `List[List[String]]` where every inner list has two elements:

```
scala> l.grouped(2).toList // the toList is to force the iterator to evaluate.
res26: List[List[String]] = List(List(key1, val1), List(key2, val2))
```

then with `collect` you match on the inner lists and create a tuple, at the end `toMap` transforms the list to a `Map`.

Comment: It's generally better to fail on unexpected data instead of silently changing it. E.g. it might be that you are losing one value in the source list due to an off-by-one mistake. With Daniel's answer you'd get an exception, investigate it and fix; with your answer you wouldn't get an exception, but just lose data and hope it's detected by tests or by inspecting the results.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov probably failing in this case makes more sense, it all comes down to OP concept of unexpected data (you could also have an even list but with two consecutive keys for example), it's hard to say from the question since there's no strict relationship between the elements of a list, but you made a good point.

Answer (score 3):

```
l.grouped(2).map { case List(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to get them into pairs then provide them to a map

```
val lst: List[String] = List("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2")
val pairs = lst zip lst.tail
val m: Map[String,String] = pairs.toMap
```

Comment: `lst zip lst.tail` returns `List((key1,val1), (val1,key2), (key2,val2))`, note the second tuple `(val1,key2)`.

Comment: Whoops, yeah that's a brain fart. 

If its not kosher to have the possibility of some values as keys in your map, I'd recommend your answer.

Comment: This code doesn't work as OP asked. Please remove the answer.